# what is the character limit of a file upload input field?

Tags: html

We are using an input field (with the "multiple" attribute)  to upload a reasonably large number of files.

```
<input id="" multiple="multiple" name="" type="file" />
```

Can someone please advise if there is a character limit on this  ? (if none is explicitly declared in the HTML) ?

From our point of view, we dont want to have a limit. Security is not really an issue as this is for an in-house web app.

Comment: Not so much a character limit, but there is a default size limit in browsers of 4MB but there is a setting you can adjust in your web.config file that will set the max file size for you

Answer (score 0):

HTML specifications do not impose a limit. What happens on the server depends on the server and the operation that the form handler is trying to perform (such as trying to store the file on disk). Robust server-side form handler should of course check for the success of operations like writing the file.

In a comment you write: “Someone I spoke to seemed to think it was 1000 characters.” This must be a misunderstanding. People upload megabytes routinely. The misunderstanding may reflect a true limit – on the size of entire form data *if* sent with the GET method (though the limit on that is about 2,000 characters and only applies to some browsers). But a form containing a file field must of course be sent with the POST method, so the limit does not apply.

Answer (score -1):

The server sets a size limit, and you can enforce it client-side with javascript and the file api. I think having "no limit" is a matter of setting the server limit to a high value, and do nothing on the client side.

(Or do you mean a limit on the number of files you can add to the `multiple` field?)

Comment: No I didnt mean't 'amount of files' but simply amount of characters. Someone I spoke to seemed to think it was 1000 characters

Comment: @swisstony But what do you mean "amount of characters"? Isn't it a file upload field? Are you talking about the length of the file names?